# Unpause this NSTimer?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I am pausing an `NSTimer` like so:

```
- (IBAction)pause 
{
    pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];
    previousFiringDate = [stopmusictimer fireDate];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate distantFuture];
    [stopmusictimer setFireDate:date]; 
}
```

I have another IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)unpausebutton 
{
    // dunno code
}
```

But I am not sure how to unpause the `NSTimer` now. Anyone, please help me! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

NSTimer instances weren't really designed to be dynamically mucked with;  the `setFireDate:` explicitly documents that doing so is relatively expensive.   Probably similar to just invalidating the old one and creating a new one.

If you are pausing the timer and then your "unpause" is always "fire right now", I'd suggest invalidating and releasing the timer on pause (release only if necessary) then simply calling the targeted method on unpause.

That would be a more typical pattern.

Comment: The problem is if I invalidate the old one and make a new one, it won't do what I want, the timer is 10 seconds. So if I want to pause it when there is 5 seconds left and make a new one, it will make a new to end in 10 seconds but I want it to end in 5 seconds. And are saying I should invalidate the old timer after I pause it?

Comment: If you pause it when there is 5 seconds left, then create a new one with 5 seconds to the end.   Note that timers are also horribly imprecise.

Comment: Ok, and that is what I am trying to do but the problem is how do I get the # of seconds it was counting down, so pretty much how do I get the '5' and then make a new one with '5' seconds remaining?

Comment: In short, you don't.  Store the start time (call `[NSDate date]`, retain that and stick it in an instance variable) and then do your date calculations based on that.  It'll end up being much more accurate than a timer anyway.